# teradata data block size and table size calculations

Tags: database-design, teradata, sizing, capacity-planning, physical-design

Been using this formula as a std for TB size calculation , as part of Cap. Planning effort . We are on TD 14

```
     ( rc *   ( rsz / ( blocksize -38) ) * blocksize ) 
      + ( SQL (sel Hashamp()+1 ; ) * 1024 ) 

rsz : row size , rc : count ( * )
```

Here actually

```
 (blocksize-38)/rsz
```

is nothing but rows / block. It comes out a fraction < 1. I think that's bad because it'd mean several blocks span a row. 
My questions are

- Do the formulas need any further honing.  Latter part after the  addition sign , provides for table header . There are NO SI's for this table - just 2 dates , 1 Integer and 1 varchar (50) with a NUPI which is NPPI . None of them are Nullable and obviously without the data , nothing is compressible to begin with ( well there's not enough data info to inc. compression now but we'd run compression scripts later )
- because it'd be several blocks spanning a row - I should be upping the block size ? how much - what should be the ideal number of rows per block.  Table data will get a  full refresh every quarter and in there'd be nothing happening in the interim

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A row in Teradata **never** spans blocks.

You simply got your calculation wrong, you talk about `(blocksize-38)/rsz`, but the actual calculation shows `rsz / ( blocksize -38)`.

As the block overhead in newer releases increased to 74 this should be the correct calculation:

```
 ( rc /  (( blocksize - 74)/rsz ) * blocksize ) 
      + ( (HASHAMP()+1  ) * 1024 )
```

It's found in 
[Sizing Base Tables, Hash Indexes, and Join Indexes](http://www.info.teradata.com/HTMLPubs/DB_TTU_15_10/Database_Management/B035_1094_151K/Database_Level_Capacity_Planning.064.079.html)

But you will notice that this approaches `rc * rsz` for larger tables. As nobody cares about small tables, I usually use this simplified calculation to size a table (you might add 1 or 2 percent to get a maximum possible size).

Edit:

Not the calculation is wrong, it's due to base data types used (probably a truncation of a `DECIMAL`). Change to a `FLOAT` or `NUMBER`:

```
 ( rc *   ( rsz / ( CAST(blocksize -74 AS FLOAT)) ) * blocksize ) 
  + ( (HASHAMP()+1  ) * 1024 )
```

Comment: Hi   Dieter . thank you for your answer. . The formula I gave is what comes out finally from this basic calculation. `Tb size = ( # blocks  * block size ) +  Header.`. Header  calculation checks  out as  expected. Number of blocks is  rc /  rows  per  block.  rows  per  block is ` block size - 38/ rsz ` . Now if you put all these  together ,  its what happens as division by division is inverse multiplication. And so that is how I got the formula above. If the  calculation approach in this comment is okay , then as I verified the above formula is what it finally comes down to.

Comment: @user1874594: Now I see. Yep, mathematically correct. But you run into trouble because of rounding/truncating :-) I'll modify my answer...

Comment: Thanks again . Links posted refer 2 version  15. I'm on 14. Would that be the same overhead or  the older 38

Comment: @user1874594: Check the manual version matching your release, should be 74, too. The number is wrong in several places in the manuals, still showing 38 while this *Block Overhead
Block Header + Block Trailer = 72 bytes + 2 bytes = 74 bytes* is correct.

Comment: Thanks . All arrows up on you !

Comment: Thanks . All arrows up on you !Had one Q on  though on DB Block Size.  I am taking 63.5 .  Based on the load and usage pattern. Any pointers to approach this value determination. TY

Comment: @user1874594: Block size depends on a *dbscontrol* setting, Filesystem 3: PermDBSize. Based on the hardware (1xxx,2xxx,6xxx) and TD release this might be up to 2047 sectors. On your system it's probably either 127 or 254, 63.5KB or 127KB. When a table is initially loaded (and Freespace still defaults to 0) all but the last block per AMP will be of the maximum size. When it's maintained by Insert/Update/Delete it will be lower, but it's always hard to know exactly, you need to run a *Ferret* to get exact details.

Comment: Hi Dieter. TY for that valuable info . I was actually talking about customizing the block size at Table Level ( here we can't <think of : )  >  running console ) . So I wanted to identify typical situations where we'd double the table DB size to 2X default Vs situations to reduce it to < default. Our default is 65, I believe. Lets say the table gets refreshed just quarterly with a full refresh.  How would a custom table level DB block have impact on performance. .e.g a update table benefits from a a custom DB block size < default.

Comment: Here is what TD gives on  choosing a custom  Table DB  block `typical block size = ROUNDUP  ( Max X 3/4,512)` Here whats the context of max block size- is it  always 130,560 bytes or it comes from system . But system wide  there's just one DB Block value which is the default DB block size ?

Comment: I had one last  Q reg. Table overhead . TD 14.1 and TD 15 manuals both give this as 74 like you said but notwithstanding this value 38 is still used for rpb calculation as `rpb=(blocksz-38)/ rsz ` ref to this link http://www.info.teradata.com/htmlpubs/DB_TTU_14_10/index.html#page/Database_Management/B035_1094_112A/ch14.064.165.html#ww15240899 I guess this is what you said was the error ?

Comment: @user1874594: Yes, 74 is correct, 38 was correct in older releases. You shouldn't care about block sizes, it's just a maximum. Only in some very specific cases for some very large tables you might think about changing it.

Comment: Hi Deiter . If 74 is the new number  then a datablock size < 74 kb is not compatible for a rpb calculation. e.g. we have somethiing like 65.xx kb.

Comment: Hi Dieter . If 74 is the new number  then a datablock size < 74 kb is not compatible for a rpb calculation. e.g. we have somethiing like 65.xx kb. & we can get an rpb value with 38  we can get  value for rpb as ( 65.5 - 38)/ 85 where rsz was 85. With 74 as overhead  it'd be  (65.5 - 74 )  a -ve number. How would one interpret this . TY again

Comment: @user1874594: 74 **bytes** are the overhead per data block. The `blocksize`  in the formula is also in bytes, not kilobytes.

Comment: Thanks for the catch -explains why rpb was coming out as < 1 which did not make sense given  that multiple blocks never span a row and its visa-versa .  So PL confirm this e.g.`rc is 5,000,000 blocksize is 65.5 kb or 65500 bytes . rsz came out 100. rpb is ( 65500 - 74 ) / 100 = 654.26  so  # Blocks is 7642.221747 ( 'floated') and so table size would be =7642.221747*65500+  (1024 * 1008)  .Result is rounded to 502 mb` Does that sound right

Comment: @user1874594:  Should be ok, now compare this to '5000000*100' plus *1 or 2 percent* :-) Btw, 1008 AMPs is a huge system...

Comment: Thank you so much for those confirmations. I just randomly picked up values to exemplify & .. simplify with 100  and 1000  figures . Our  systems is far  smaller than that... you are right. Thanks again

Comment: and also yep... the 1% is right on dot with +4mb.  Makes sense to just thumb using the 1-2% rule